# how to grep exact match of a string with dots in it in a ksh

Tags: regex, grep

I am unable to get the exact matching string as output while trying to grep for a string which has dot in it.

eg: `grep "APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL" <FILENAME>`

I have even tried:

`grep -F 'APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL' <FILENAME>` which also displays lines with similar matches like `APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL1`.

Please, help me.

Comment: For what it's worth, which shell you use does not influence how `grep` works. (In pathological cases, how to properly quote a regex might differ between shells, but you have simple straightforward quoting here.)

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using `-F` which would interpret the pattern as a *fixed string*, you'd need to supply the `-x` option to match exactly the whole line.

```
grep -Fx 'APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL' filename
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)

   -x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
          (-x is specified by POSIX.)
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL
1APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL
APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL1
APPLICATION.REFERENCE0LOCAL
$ grep -Fx 'APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL' file
APPLICATION.REFERENCE.LOCAL
```

Comment: I like the use of `-Fx` for this purpose.

Comment: @Floris Since OP has used `-F`, the `^` & `$` anchors would be interpreted as literals.  `-x` matches the whole line.

Comment: Which is why, in my answer, I took out the `-F` and put in the anchors and escaped the `.` . You went the other way. My answer addresses more generally "how do I use regex when there is a dot in the string I want to match"; yours is a cleaner answer to the specific example given. Both add something to the discussion, I think. Which is why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Floris Yes, I completely agree.  Yours educates about anchors and escaping the metacharacters.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the dot with a backslash:

```
grep 'APPLICATION\.REFERENCE\.LOCAL'
```

and if you want "only and exactly this" in the line, you need to anchor with the "start and end of string" characters:

```
grep '^APPLICATION\.REFERENCE\.LOCAL$'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to constrain to matches at word boundaries, add `-w`. So `grep -Fw string file`

If the definition of "word boundary" is too relaxed for you, you will need to specify the boundary in regex. Something like this, maybe:

```
grep -E (^|[^A-Z])APPLICATION\.REFERENCE\.LOCAL([^A-Z]|$)' file
```

will only find matches which are bounded by beginning/end of line, or a character which is not an uppercase alphabetic.

Comment: The use of `grep -E` is not absolutely necessary if you have GNU `grep`, but it's simpler and portable across POSIX.