# grep -c value NH:i:1 only for every line in file, not also NH:i:12

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

```
cat samtry.txt | grep -c NH:i:1
```

See an example of three lines below. the bold information is whats important

```
HWI-ST697:178:D1U9CACXX:1:2111:12787:5687   153 scaffold_1  33005   50  101M    *   0   0   GACTAAGGAAGTCATCTGCAGTGCCCCTTGCACTTCCTAATGGGACTTTCCCTGGTTGACTATTCTTACTATGAGAACAATGAGCACCAGCTTCATTCACA   DCDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEFGHGJIHGHFHJIJIJJIJJJJIHJJIJIIIFJJIGGGIJJJIIJJHIGJIJJJGHJJIJIJIGFJJGHHHHFFFFFCCC   AS:i:-11    XN:i:0  XM:i:2  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:2  MD:Z:18T26G55YT:Z:UU    **NH:i:1**
HWI-ST697:178:D1U9CACXX:3:1310:18383:72540  89  scaffold_1  33005   50  101M    *   0   0   GACTAAGGAAGTCATCTGCAGTGCCCCTTGCACTTCCTAATGGGACTTTCCCTGGTTGACTATTCTTACTATGAGAACAATGAGCACCAGCTTCATTCACA   DDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEFFFHHHIIJJIIIJIJJJJJJJJJJHJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJIJJJJJJJJIHFJJHHHHHFFFFFCCC   AS:i:-11    XN:i:0  XM:i:2  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:2  MD:Z:18T26G55YT:Z:UU    **NH:i:11**
HWI-ST697:178:D1U9CACXX:7:1212:17559:76798  89  scaffold_1  33007   50  101M    *   0   0   CTAAGGAAGTCATCTGCAGTGCCCCTTGCACTTCCTAATGGGACTTTCCCTGGTTGACTATTCTTACTATGAGAACAATGAGCACCAGCTTCATTCACAAG   DDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEECDFFHGHIGJIIHJJJIIJJJJJJHHJJJJJJJJJJJIIIJJJJGIIGBJJIJJJJIJJJJJIHHHFJJIJHHHHGFFFFFCCC   AS:i:-11    XN:i:0  XM:i:2  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:2  MD:Z:16T26G57YT:Z:UU    **NH:i:1**
```

I am trying to use a shell script to count all the lines in a tab-delimited-file (testfile: `samtry.txt`, contains 10 lines to test on) that contains the following Regular expression `NH:i:1` 
The problem is of course that I get the information I wanted; but it also counts the lines with the following outcome: `NH:i:1x` (where x is any possible digit: 0-9)
The position of the `NH:i:x` (x = any digit until around 50) is in every line of the file on 20, its not the last position of the line. Every line has 23 'positions'.

Does anyone know how to do this with grep or another tool?

I've got around 100 files which each have a size of around 3GB each, and I don't know how to solve this problem

I hope I give enough information, I am happy for every answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grep exact match of a string with dots in it in a ksh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721355/how-to-grep-exact-match-of-a-string-with-dots-in-it-in-a-ksh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grep` with word boundaries:

```
grep -c '\<NH:i:1\>' samtry.txt
```

OR `grep -w`:

```
grep -wc 'NH:i:1' samtry.txt
```